# How to configure shortcut too toggle keyboard light

Tags: keyboard, mac, applications, shortcut, shortcuts-app

How to configure shortcut to toggle keyboard light on and off on MacBook Air M2?
Like I am have set it to 20% and when I press shortcut it sets to 0%, then if I press the shortcut again it sets to 20% again(toggling).
I am tired to enter setting, or open menubar thing to add 1% of keyboard backlight to type 10 words and then turn it back off. Any app for this situation?

Comment: @Thinkr It is not what I mean. If you think I do have buttons to toggle it on/off, I do not. Suchk keys were on older Macs, but not on mine MacBook  Air M2 2022.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard backlight has a timer. No need for 'tiresome' shortcuts.

System Settings | Keyboard | Turn Keyboard Backlight Off After Inactivity

Your setting might be on 'never' by default.

Comment: I do know about it. I mean, its dark, you are doing some stuff that you do not need to look at keyboard permanently (gaming, touch typing) and most of the time it glowing for no reason because I turned it on to find some special shortcut and do not want to go to settings to turn it off.